# Auto resizing constraints

Tags: resize, constraints

I try to create UIView with auto resizing constraints. The goal is so simple. I need UIView that will transform its size according to device screen. I created three constraints that align to safeArea and one with offset. But when I change Device in a storyboard view, it always appears some gap in the bottom constrain.

In this view, everything is ok. This where I created all constraints[image]

But in all others it's terrible gap. [image][image]

Does anybody have an adea how to fix that? Unfortunately I don't understand where I did mistake.